# Python - Criando programa que altere ele mesmo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Gostaria de criar um programa que seja capaz de alterar ele mesmo, ou seja, eu executo o script, e ele muda o próprio script.py, criando uma espécie de marcador.

O grande problema é que não consigo alterar o programa quando ele está rodando, como fiz abaixo:

```
arq = open("./01_programa_alterar.py")
lines = arq.readlines()

x = False  # lines[4] = "x = True\n"

if x:
    print("Você Alterou o script")
else:
    print("Script não alterado")


#----mudar script----
lines[4] = "x = True\n"  # Pulo do gato

for line in lines:
    arq.write(line)
#--------------------

arq.close()
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algum módulo que faça essa alteração :(

Comment: Já tentou colocar o `arq.close()` antes do `x = False` ?

Comment: primeiro li o arquivo no modo 'r' depois fechei, então depois abri novamente no modo "w"

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer funcionar da seguinte maneira:

```
#Ler arquivo
arq = open(__file__, 'r')
lines = arq.readlines() #Leremos por aqui
arq.close()

x = False

if x:
    print("Você Alterou o script")
else:
    print("Script não alterado")

#Escrever arquivo (Não ler linhas)
arq = open(__file__, 'w')

#----mudar script----
lines[5] = "x = True\n"

for line in lines:
    arq.write(line)
#--------------------

arq.close()
```

Eu estava esquecendo de fechar o arquivo e depois abrir ele novamente com, só que no como "w" open(**file**,'w') ...

Comment: Como eu tinha dito.